# Does $\mathscr{B}(C(\Bbb{R}_+\rightarrow \Bbb{R}))=\bigotimes_{t\in \Bbb{R}_+}\mathscr{B}(\Bbb{R})$?

Tags: measure-theory, stochastic-processes

I am looking at the definition of a Wiener measure and its connection to the probability law of a stochastic process. From what I have read (in çinlar, 2011) the probablity law (i.e. probability distribution) of a stocastic process $\{X_t\}_{t\in T}$, where $X_t$ are random variables to $(E,\varepsilon)$, is defined as the probability distribution of the random variable $X:\omega\mapsto X(\omega)$ which is considered on $(E^T,\varepsilon ^T)$ where :
$$\varepsilon^T=\bigotimes_{t\in T}\varepsilon$$
Now I know that the Wiener measure is defined on $(C,\mathscr{B}(C))$ (where $C=C(\Bbb{R}_+\rightarrow \Bbb{R})$). This poses the question of whether:

$$\mathscr{B}(C)=\bigotimes_{t\in \Bbb{R}_+}\mathscr{B}(\Bbb{R})$$
which would make these definitions coincide, since the rvs in Wiener processes are defined on $(\Bbb{R},\mathscr{B}(\Bbb{R}))$. Is this the case? and if so how do we prove it?

**EDIT: Comment On Notation**

From what I have read $\bigotimes_{t\in \Bbb{R}_+}\mathscr{B}(\Bbb{R})$ is not a litutral tensor product. It signifies the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the measurable rectangles of $C$ i.e.:
$$\bigotimes_{t\in \Bbb{R}_+}\mathscr{B}(\Bbb{R})=\sigma\left( \{f\in C |f(t)\in A_t \forall t \in T \; \&\; A_t \in \mathscr{B}(\Bbb{R})\}\right)$$

Comment: On your edit: so it is not the smallest $\sigma$-algebra such that all projections $\pi_t:C\to\mathbb R$ prescribed by $f\mapsto f(t)$ are measurable?

Comment: @drhab I wouldn't be able to answer this with any degree of confidence. The interpretation I have given above is from (çinlar, 2011), but don't know if this is the standard interpretation.